# Opengl cube map - different results for freeimage and stb image libs

Tags: opengl, freeimage

I'm trying to understand cube maps. I have read the following tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps My example program is very similar to the tutorial program but I use freeimage for loading textures. My cube map has inverted y view for each face. When I change texture library from stb image to freeimage in the tutorial program I also get inverted y view for each face. Does freeimage use some non-standard convention ? Why I get different results ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a standard for this, but I wouldn't say that **FreeImage** is mirroring the image vertically, it's just the way pixel data is stored. 
If you want to read the data with an OpenGL generated texture, you may want to flip the images by code using `FreeImage_FlipVertical` before `FreeImage_GetBits`. I guess you are using `FreeImage_GetBits` to deliver the data to the texture generated in OpenGL, if you are reading the image with scan lines, you can load the data from the bottom up.

Heads-up: If you use multiple formats of images It is likely that you also have other problems regarding the way data is stored, so just to let you know, when you use GetBits and GetScanLine, in the official FreeImage documentation says "*It is up to you to interpret these bytes correctly, according to the results of `FreeImage_GetBPP`, `FreeImage_GetRedMask`, `FreeImage_GetGreenMask` and `FreeImage_GetBlueMask`*" so if you have other problems loading the image to OpenGL you may want to check the examples here for interpreting the data:
 http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/documentation.html